# Add a class to posts in increments of 2

Tags: jquery, css, query

Is it possible to add specific classes to posts/pages in a query in increments of 2?

For example

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3 (add custom class)
- Post 4 (add custom class)
- Post 5
- Post 6
- Post 7 (add custom class)
- Post 8 (add custom class)
- Post 9

I don't mind using jQuery if needs be.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you looked into how to add classes to post in general for starters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `post_class`, use a static internal counter in the filter callback:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse_100804_post_class' );

function wpse_100804_post_class( $classes )
{
    static $counter = 0;
    $counter += 1;

    switch ( $counter )
    {
        case 4:
            $counter = 0;
        case 3:
            $classes[] = 'extra';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

In your loop template call `post_class()` like this:

```
while ( have_posts() )
{
    the_post();
    ?><li <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php /* more stuff */ ?>
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a theme you can safely edit (ie. one you have built) then in your Loop, keep track of the posts on a cycle of 4.

```
$qry = new WP_Query("showposts=10");
if ($qry->have_posts()) {
  $iter = 0;
  while($qry->have_posts()) {
    $iter++;
    $extra_class = '';
    $qry->the_post();

    if (3 == $iter || 4 == $iter) {
      $extra_class = 'extra-class';
    }

    echo '<div ',post_class($extra_class),'>';
      the_title();
    echo '</div>';

    if (4 == $iter) {
      $iter = 0;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version, using `modulus 4` on the `$wp_query->current_post`

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li <?php echo ( $wp_query->current_post % 4 > 1 ) ? " class='custom-class' " : ""; ?>>
        <?php the_title();?>
    </li>
endwhile;
```

Here is a table showing what happens when `$wp_query->current_post % 4 > 1`

[image]

Comment: Post 6 should _not_ get this class, but post 3 should.

Comment: `$wp_query->current_post` starts from `0` so I think it should be ok

Comment: I added a table to the answer to convince myself ;-)

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the edit, I had duplicated `the_post()`, this can happen in a nightly answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper function for things like this. It's the first thing in all of my themes' functions.php files.

```
/**
 * Cycle/alternate unlimited values of a given array.
 * For instance, if you call this function five times with wp_cycle('three', 'two', 'one'),
 * you will in return get: three two one three two. This is useful for loops and allows you to
 * cycle classes.
 * For instance, foreach ($posts as $post) { echo '<div class="'.wp_cycle('odd','even').'">...</div>'; }
 * would alternate between <div class="odd">...</div> and <div class="even">...</div>. Neat, huh?
 * You can pass any data as args and as many as you want, e.g. wp_cycle(array('foo', 'bar'), false, 5, 'silly')
 *
 * @param mixed Accepts unlimited args
 * @return mixed
 * @author Matthew Boynes
 */
function wp_cycle() {
    global $wp_cycle_curr_index;
    $args = func_get_args();
    $fingerprint = substr( sha1( serialize( $args ) ), 0, 7 );
    if ( !is_array( $wp_cycle_curr_index) ) $wp_cycle_curr_index = array();
    if ( !isset( $wp_cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] ) || !is_int( $wp_cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] ) ) $wp_cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] = -1;
    $wp_cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] = ++$wp_cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] % count( $args );
    return $args[ $wp_cycle_curr_index[ $fingerprint ] ];
}
```

Once you add it to your functions.php file, to use it in the loop is very simple. Here's an example:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="<?php post_class( wp_cycle( '', '', 'custom-class', 'custom-class' ) ) ?>">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

One caveat: in the event WordPress ever adds something like this to core, I always replace wp_ with something less generic and more site-specific. For instance, if I were making a website for CNN, it would be cnn_cycle.